# unicode of lower case and upper case letters

Tags: unicode

what are the corresponding unicode values of lower case and upper case letters from a
 to z

Comment: The response to this question should be to just google it.
A google of "unicode table" returns everything you need.

Comment: I don't agree. This discussion is been held some time ago and stackoverflow wants all programming related questions.

Comment: @Gamecat, I agree.  In fact I'd go futher links in answers are useful but having the actual answer in SO itself is better.

Comment: As can be seen from the various answers and comments there are clearly two camps regarding how this question is to be interpreted. Maybe the OP can edit it to make clear what he really wanted to ask? As it is "just google it" seems to be as good an answer as any.

Answer (score 17):

Same as ASCII (but with leading 0s :)

A-Z = U+0041 - U+005A = 65-90 decimal

a-z = U+0061 - U+007A = 97-122 decimal

Comment: dammit, 13 seconds faster! ;)

Comment: The answer is not complete. The mapping between lower and upper case letters is language-specific. For instance, in Turkish the lower case i corresponds to the upper case İ (dotted I) and the "plain" upper case I corresponds to lower case ı (dotless i)

Comment: The OP only asked about the ASCII letters.  This answer looks complete to me.

Answer (score 10):

Same as ASCII. All ASCII characters have the same values in Unicode.

Answer (score 8):

The answer largely depends on your language. Answers here are good for English language, but some languages contain additional characters which sometimes even change to two characters depending on the case (or two to one inversely) - Turkish comes to mind.

Comment: While I agree with the general idea behind the answer - this does not really match the question, as neither umlaut characters nor "ß" are between a and z.

Comment: "neither umlaut characters nor ß are between a and z" - maybe not in your alphabet. ;]

Comment: It definitely depends on how you read the question. I read it as "A-Z" and "a-z" rather than "a-z" and "upper-cased in a culturally sensitive manner a-z". I agree it's good to know about that though.

Comment: @bzlm: No. There simply is no space left between U+0041 and U+005A or between U+0061 and U+007A for any umlaut characters. Regardless of alphabet. There was no mention in the question about language-correct sorting or anything like that.

Comment: And if that was actually what was wanted, why did the OP ask for "unicode values of lower case and upper case letters from a to z" instead of "unicode values of lower case and upper case letters"?

Comment: mghie: I don't know which Germany you come from but in my Duden, “ä” has the same lexicographical ordering as “a”. ;-) The question wasn't about U+0061–U+007A but rather about A–Z. I think awareness about these facts is very beneficial for programmers. Apart from that, you're obviously right.

Comment: +1 for the answer. The mapping of lower case to upper case letters is language-specific and Turkish (i, I, ı) is a good example of that.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: OK, but none of us is psychic. It'd be best if the question was edited by the OP. It would be easier to find it in searches later on, too. BTW, I suppose I come from the very same Germany as you, but one never knows ;-)

Comment: Unix grep and probably other Unix regexps include several hundred characters in [a-z] in a UTF-8 locale. Even in command-line Unix, a-z doesn't necessarily mean between U+0061 and U+007A.

Answer (score 7):

The [Unicode code charts](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) will probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are hex tables here:
http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

But they are the same as ASCII anyway.

Answer (score -2):

A-Z:65-90(for lower case characters)
a-z:97-122(for upper case characters)