# RegEx for Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols

Tags: php, regex, pcre, symbolic-math

I have been trying to remove bold characters like this:

```
 - New song
```

As you see is a bold text without `<b>` tag.

I had tried this, assuming that the characters are probably a type of emoticon, but I have not had any luck.

```
$regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $string);

$regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

$regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

$regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

$regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);
```

How can I remove it or replace for correct char without bold? 
Any idea it will be apreciated.

Comment: This `` is clearly a _bold_ font look but is most likely   it's own Unicode character _bold_ font. As far as font's go, its probably singular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These characters belong to the Unicode ***`Mathematical`*** code block

`\p{Block=Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols}` which covers the range  `[\x{1D400}-\x{1D7FF}]`

These characters are a mix of font looking codes like bold, italic-bold, script, script-italic, script-italic-bold.

They could be mapped to ASCII equivalent if you want to take the time to match each type and range.

I would just delete them.

***Here are the characters in the block range ( heavily abbreviated )***

```
1D400     M BLD CAP A
1D401     M BLD CAP B
1D402     M BLD CAP C
1D403     M BLD CAP D
1D404     M BLD CAP E
1D405     M BLD CAP F
1D406     M BLD CAP G
1D407     M BLD CAP H
1D408     M BLD CAP I
1D409     M BLD CAP J
1D40A     M BLD CAP K
1D40B     M BLD CAP L
1D40C     M BLD CAP M
1D40D     M BLD CAP N
1D40E     M BLD CAP O
1D40F     M BLD CAP P
1D410     M BLD CAP Q
1D411     M BLD CAP R
1D412     M BLD CAP S
1D413     M BLD CAP T
1D414     M BLD CAP U
1D415     M BLD CAP V
1D416     M BLD CAP W
1D417     M BLD CAP X
1D418     M BLD CAP Y
1D419     M BLD CAP Z
1D41A     M BLD SML A
1D41B     M BLD SML B
1D41C     M BLD SML C
1D41D     M BLD SML D
1D41E     M BLD SML E
1D41F     M BLD SML F
1D420     M BLD SML G
1D421     M BLD SML H
1D422     M BLD SML I
1D423     M BLD SML J
1D424     M BLD SML K
1D425     M BLD SML L
1D426     M BLD SML M
1D427     M BLD SML N
1D428     M BLD SML O
1D429     M BLD SML P
1D42A     M BLD SML Q
1D42B     M BLD SML R
1D42C     M BLD SML S
1D42D     M BLD SML T
1D42E     M BLD SML U
1D42F     M BLD SML V
1D430     M BLD SML W
1D431     M BLD SML X
1D432     M BLD SML Y
1D433     M BLD SML Z
1D434     M ITAL CAP A
1D435     M ITAL CAP B
1D436     M ITAL CAP C
1D437     M ITAL CAP D
1D438     M ITAL CAP E
1D439     M ITAL CAP F
1D43A     M ITAL CAP G
1D43B     M ITAL CAP H
1D43C     M ITAL CAP I
1D43D     M ITAL CAP J
1D43E     M ITAL CAP K
1D43F     M ITAL CAP L
1D440     M ITAL CAP M
1D441     M ITAL CAP N
1D442     M ITAL CAP O
1D443     M ITAL CAP P
1D444     M ITAL CAP Q
1D445     M ITAL CAP R
1D446     M ITAL CAP S
1D447     M ITAL CAP T
1D448     M ITAL CAP U
1D449     M ITAL CAP V
1D44A     M ITAL CAP W
1D44B     M ITAL CAP X
1D44C     M ITAL CAP Y
1D44D     M ITAL CAP Z
1D44E     M ITAL SML A
1D44F     M ITAL SML B
1D450     M ITAL SML C
1D451     M ITAL SML D
1D452     M ITAL SML E
1D453     M ITAL SML F
1D454     M ITAL SML G
1D455     <unassigned-1D455>
1D456     M ITAL SML I
1D457     M ITAL SML J
1D458     M ITAL SML K
1D459     M ITAL SML L
1D45A     M ITAL SML M
1D45B     M ITAL SML N
1D45C     M ITAL SML O
1D45D     M ITAL SML P
1D45E     M ITAL SML Q
1D45F     M ITAL SML R
1D460     M ITAL SML S
1D461     M ITAL SML T
1D462     M ITAL SML U
1D463     M ITAL SML V
1D464     M ITAL SML W
1D465     M ITAL SML X
1D466     M ITAL SML Y
1D467     M ITAL SML Z
1D468     M BLD ITAL CAP A
1D469     M BLD ITAL CAP B
1D46A     M BLD ITAL CAP C
1D46B     M BLD ITAL CAP D
1D46C     M BLD ITAL CAP E
1D46D     M BLD ITAL CAP F
1D46E     M BLD ITAL CAP G
1D46F     M BLD ITAL CAP H
1D470     M BLD ITAL CAP I
1D471     M BLD ITAL CAP J
1D472     M BLD ITAL CAP K
1D473     M BLD ITAL CAP L
1D474     M BLD ITAL CAP M
1D475     M BLD ITAL CAP N
1D476     M BLD ITAL CAP O
1D477     M BLD ITAL CAP P
1D478     M BLD ITAL CAP Q
1D479     M BLD ITAL CAP R
1D47A     M BLD ITAL CAP S
1D47B     M BLD ITAL CAP T
1D47C     M BLD ITAL CAP U
1D47D     M BLD ITAL CAP V
1D47E     M BLD ITAL CAP W
1D47F     M BLD ITAL CAP X
1D480     M BLD ITAL CAP Y
1D481     M BLD ITAL CAP Z
1D482     M BLD ITAL SML A
1D483     M BLD ITAL SML B
1D484     M BLD ITAL SML C
1D485     M BLD ITAL SML D
1D486     M BLD ITAL SML E
1D487     M BLD ITAL SML F
1D488     M BLD ITAL SML G
1D489     M BLD ITAL SML H
1D48A     M BLD ITAL SML I
1D48B     M BLD ITAL SML J
1D48C     M BLD ITAL SML K
1D48D     M BLD ITAL SML L
1D48E     M BLD ITAL SML M
1D48F     M BLD ITAL SML N
1D490     M BLD ITAL SML O
1D491     M BLD ITAL SML P
1D492     M BLD ITAL SML Q
1D493     M BLD ITAL SML R
1D494     M BLD ITAL SML S
1D495     M BLD ITAL SML T
1D496     M BLD ITAL SML U
1D497     M BLD ITAL SML V
1D498     M BLD ITAL SML W
1D499     M BLD ITAL SML X
1D49A     M BLD ITAL SML Y
1D49B     M BLD ITAL SML Z
1D49C     M SCR CAP A
1D49D     <unassigned-1D49D>
1D49E     M SCR CAP C
1D49F     M SCR CAP D
1D4A0     <unassigned-1D4A0>
1D4A1     <unassigned-1D4A1>
1D4A2     M SCR CAP G
1D4A3     <unassigned-1D4A3>
1D4A4     <unassigned-1D4A4>
1D4A5     M SCR CAP J
1D4A6     M SCR CAP K
1D4A7     <unassigned-1D4A7>
1D4A8     <unassigned-1D4A8>
1D4A9     M SCR CAP N
1D4AA     M SCR CAP O
1D4AB     M SCR CAP P
1D4AC     M SCR CAP Q
1D4AD     <unassigned-1D4AD>
1D4AE     M SCR CAP S
1D4AF     M SCR CAP T
1D4B0     M SCR CAP U
1D4B1     M SCR CAP V
1D4B2     M SCR CAP W
1D4B3     M SCR CAP X
1D4B4     M SCR CAP Y
1D4B5     M SCR CAP Z
1D4B6     M SCR SML A
1D4B7     M SCR SML B
1D4B8     M SCR SML C
1D4B9     M SCR SML D
1D4BA     <unassigned-1D4BA>
1D4BB     M SCR SML F
1D4BC     <unassigned-1D4BC>
1D4BD     M SCR SML H
1D4BE     M SCR SML I
1D4BF     M SCR SML J
1D4C0     M SCR SML K
1D4C1     M SCR SML L
1D4C2     M SCR SML M
1D4C3     M SCR SML N
1D4C4     <unassigned-1D4C4>
1D4C5     M SCR SML P
1D4C6     M SCR SML Q
1D4C7     M SCR SML R
1D4C8     M SCR SML S
1D4C9     M SCR SML T
1D4CA     M SCR SML U
1D4CB     M SCR SML V
1D4CC     M SCR SML W
1D4CD     M SCR SML X
1D4CE     M SCR SML Y
1D4CF     M SCR SML Z
1D4D0     M BLD SCR CAP A
1D4D1     M BLD SCR CAP B
1D4D2     M BLD SCR CAP C
1D4D3     M BLD SCR CAP D
1D4D4     M BLD SCR CAP E
1D4D5     M BLD SCR CAP F
1D4D6     M BLD SCR CAP G
1D4D7     M BLD SCR CAP H
1D4D8     M BLD SCR CAP I
1D4D9     M BLD SCR CAP J
1D4DA     M BLD SCR CAP K
1D4DB     M BLD SCR CAP L
1D4DC     M BLD SCR CAP M
1D4DD     M BLD SCR CAP N
1D4DE     M BLD SCR CAP O
1D4DF     M BLD SCR CAP P
1D4E0     M BLD SCR CAP Q
1D4E1     M BLD SCR CAP R
1D4E2     M BLD SCR CAP S
1D4E3     M BLD SCR CAP T
1D4E4     M BLD SCR CAP U
1D4E5     M BLD SCR CAP V
1D4E6     M BLD SCR CAP W
1D4E7     M BLD SCR CAP X
1D4E8     M BLD SCR CAP Y
1D4E9     M BLD SCR CAP Z
1D4EA     M BLD SCR SML A
1D4EB     M BLD SCR SML B
1D4EC     M BLD SCR SML C
1D4ED     M BLD SCR SML D
1D4EE     M BLD SCR SML E
1D4EF     M BLD SCR SML F
1D4F0     M BLD SCR SML G
1D4F1     M BLD SCR SML H
1D4F2     M BLD SCR SML I
1D4F3     M BLD SCR SML J
1D4F4     M BLD SCR SML K
1D4F5     M BLD SCR SML L
1D4F6     M BLD SCR SML M
1D4F7     M BLD SCR SML N
1D4F8     M BLD SCR SML O
1D4F9     M BLD SCR SML P
1D4FA     M BLD SCR SML Q
1D4FB     M BLD SCR SML R
1D4FC     M BLD SCR SML S
1D4FD     M BLD SCR SML T
1D4FE     M BLD SCR SML U
1D4FF     M BLD SCR SML V
1D500     M BLD SCR SML W
1D501     M BLD SCR SML X
1D502     M BLD SCR SML Y
1D503     M BLD SCR SML Z
1D504     M FRAK CAP A
1D505     M FRAK CAP B
1D506     <unassigned-1D506>
1D507     M FRAK CAP D
1D508     M FRAK CAP E
1D509     M FRAK CAP F
1D50A     M FRAK CAP G
1D50B     <unassigned-1D50B>
1D50C     <unassigned-1D50C>
1D50D     M FRAK CAP J
1D50E     M FRAK CAP K
1D50F     M FRAK CAP L
1D510     M FRAK CAP M
1D511     M FRAK CAP N
1D512     M FRAK CAP O
1D513     M FRAK CAP P
1D514     M FRAK CAP Q
1D515     <unassigned-1D515>
1D516     M FRAK CAP S
1D517     M FRAK CAP T
1D518     M FRAK CAP U
1D519     M FRAK CAP V
1D51A     M FRAK CAP W
1D51B     M FRAK CAP X
1D51C     M FRAK CAP Y
1D51D     <unassigned-1D51D>
1D51E     M FRAK SML A
1D51F     M FRAK SML B
1D520     M FRAK SML C
1D521     M FRAK SML D
1D522     M FRAK SML E
1D523     M FRAK SML F
1D524     M FRAK SML G
1D525     M FRAK SML H
1D526     M FRAK SML I
1D527     M FRAK SML J
1D528     M FRAK SML K
1D529     M FRAK SML L
1D52A     M FRAK SML M
1D52B     M FRAK SML N
1D52C     M FRAK SML O
1D52D     M FRAK SML P
1D52E     M FRAK SML Q
1D52F     M FRAK SML R
1D530     M FRAK SML S
1D531     M FRAK SML T
1D532     M FRAK SML U
1D533     M FRAK SML V
1D534     M FRAK SML W
1D535     M FRAK SML X
1D536     M FRAK SML Y
1D537     M FRAK SML Z
1D538     M DBL-STR CAP A
1D539     M DBL-STR CAP B
1D53A     <unassigned-1D53A>
1D53B     M DBL-STR CAP D
1D53C     M DBL-STR CAP E
1D53D     M DBL-STR CAP F
1D53E     M DBL-STR CAP G
1D53F     <unassigned-1D53F>
1D540     M DBL-STR CAP I
1D541     M DBL-STR CAP J
1D542     M DBL-STR CAP K
1D543     M DBL-STR CAP L
1D544     M DBL-STR CAP M
1D545     <unassigned-1D545>
1D546     M DBL-STR CAP O
1D547     <unassigned-1D547>
1D548     <unassigned-1D548>
1D549     <unassigned-1D549>
1D54A     M DBL-STR CAP S
1D54B     M DBL-STR CAP T
1D54C     M DBL-STR CAP U
1D54D     M DBL-STR CAP V
1D54E     M DBL-STR CAP W
1D54F     M DBL-STR CAP X
1D550     M DBL-STR CAP Y
1D551     <unassigned-1D551>
1D552     M DBL-STR SML A
1D553     M DBL-STR SML B
1D554     M DBL-STR SML C
1D555     M DBL-STR SML D
1D556     M DBL-STR SML E
1D557     M DBL-STR SML F
1D558     M DBL-STR SML G
1D559     M DBL-STR SML H
1D55A     M DBL-STR SML I
1D55B     M DBL-STR SML J
1D55C     M DBL-STR SML K
1D55D     M DBL-STR SML L
1D55E     M DBL-STR SML M
1D55F     M DBL-STR SML N
1D560     M DBL-STR SML O
1D561     M DBL-STR SML P
1D562     M DBL-STR SML Q
1D563     M DBL-STR SML R
1D564     M DBL-STR SML S
1D565     M DBL-STR SML T
1D566     M DBL-STR SML U
1D567     M DBL-STR SML V
1D568     M DBL-STR SML W
1D569     M DBL-STR SML X
1D56A     M DBL-STR SML Y
1D56B     M DBL-STR SML Z
1D56C     M BLD FRAK CAP A
1D56D     M BLD FRAK CAP B
1D56E     M BLD FRAK CAP C
1D56F     M BLD FRAK CAP D
1D570     M BLD FRAK CAP E
1D571     M BLD FRAK CAP F
1D572     M BLD FRAK CAP G
1D573     M BLD FRAK CAP H
1D574     M BLD FRAK CAP I
1D575     M BLD FRAK CAP J
1D576     M BLD FRAK CAP K
1D577     M BLD FRAK CAP L
1D578     M BLD FRAK CAP M
1D579     M BLD FRAK CAP N
1D57A     M BLD FRAK CAP O
1D57B     M BLD FRAK CAP P
1D57C     M BLD FRAK CAP Q
1D57D     M BLD FRAK CAP R
1D57E     M BLD FRAK CAP S
1D57F     M BLD FRAK CAP T
1D580     M BLD FRAK CAP U
1D581     M BLD FRAK CAP V
1D582     M BLD FRAK CAP W
1D583     M BLD FRAK CAP X
1D584     M BLD FRAK CAP Y
1D585     M BLD FRAK CAP Z
1D586     M BLD FRAK SML A
1D587     M BLD FRAK SML B
1D588     M BLD FRAK SML C
1D589     M BLD FRAK SML D
1D58A     M BLD FRAK SML E
1D58B     M BLD FRAK SML F
1D58C     M BLD FRAK SML G
1D58D     M BLD FRAK SML H
1D58E     M BLD FRAK SML I
1D58F     M BLD FRAK SML J
1D590     M BLD FRAK SML K
1D591     M BLD FRAK SML L
1D592     M BLD FRAK SML M
1D593     M BLD FRAK SML N
1D594     M BLD FRAK SML O
1D595     M BLD FRAK SML P
1D596     M BLD FRAK SML Q
1D597     M BLD FRAK SML R
1D598     M BLD FRAK SML S
1D599     M BLD FRAK SML T
1D59A     M BLD FRAK SML U
1D59B     M BLD FRAK SML V
1D59C     M BLD FRAK SML W
1D59D     M BLD FRAK SML X
1D59E     M BLD FRAK SML Y
1D59F     M BLD FRAK SML Z
1D5A0     M S-SER CAP A
1D5A1     M S-SER CAP B
1D5A2     M S-SER CAP C
1D5A3     M S-SER CAP D
1D5A4     M S-SER CAP E
1D5A5     M S-SER CAP F
1D5A6     M S-SER CAP G
1D5A7     M S-SER CAP H
1D5A8     M S-SER CAP I
1D5A9     M S-SER CAP J
1D5AA     M S-SER CAP K
1D5AB     M S-SER CAP L
1D5AC     M S-SER CAP M
1D5AD     M S-SER CAP N
1D5AE     M S-SER CAP O
1D5AF     M S-SER CAP P
1D5B0     M S-SER CAP Q
1D5B1     M S-SER CAP R
1D5B2     M S-SER CAP S
1D5B3     M S-SER CAP T
1D5B4     M S-SER CAP U
1D5B5     M S-SER CAP V
1D5B6     M S-SER CAP W
1D5B7     M S-SER CAP X
1D5B8     M S-SER CAP Y
1D5B9     M S-SER CAP Z
1D5BA     M S-SER SML A
1D5BB     M S-SER SML B
1D5BC     M S-SER SML C
1D5BD     M S-SER SML D
1D5BE     M S-SER SML E
1D5BF     M S-SER SML F
1D5C0     M S-SER SML G
1D5C1     M S-SER SML H
1D5C2     M S-SER SML I
1D5C3     M S-SER SML J
1D5C4     M S-SER SML K
1D5C5     M S-SER SML L
1D5C6     M S-SER SML M
1D5C7     M S-SER SML N
1D5C8     M S-SER SML O
1D5C9     M S-SER SML P
1D5CA     M S-SER SML Q
1D5CB     M S-SER SML R
1D5CC     M S-SER SML S
1D5CD     M S-SER SML T
1D5CE     M S-SER SML U
1D5CF     M S-SER SML V
1D5D0     M S-SER SML W
1D5D1     M S-SER SML X
1D5D2     M S-SER SML Y
1D5D3     M S-SER SML Z
1D5D4     M S-SER BLD CAP A
1D5D5     M S-SER BLD CAP B
1D5D6     M S-SER BLD CAP C
1D5D7     M S-SER BLD CAP D
1D5D8     M S-SER BLD CAP E
1D5D9     M S-SER BLD CAP F
1D5DA     M S-SER BLD CAP G
1D5DB     M S-SER BLD CAP H
1D5DC     M S-SER BLD CAP I
1D5DD     M S-SER BLD CAP J
1D5DE     M S-SER BLD CAP K
1D5DF     M S-SER BLD CAP L
1D5E0     M S-SER BLD CAP M
1D5E1     M S-SER BLD CAP N
1D5E2     M S-SER BLD CAP O
1D5E3     M S-SER BLD CAP P
1D5E4     M S-SER BLD CAP Q
1D5E5     M S-SER BLD CAP R
1D5E6     M S-SER BLD CAP S
1D5E7     M S-SER BLD CAP T
1D5E8     M S-SER BLD CAP U
1D5E9     M S-SER BLD CAP V
1D5EA     M S-SER BLD CAP W
1D5EB     M S-SER BLD CAP X
1D5EC     M S-SER BLD CAP Y
1D5ED     M S-SER BLD CAP Z
1D5EE     M S-SER BLD SML A
1D5EF     M S-SER BLD SML B
1D5F0     M S-SER BLD SML C
1D5F1     M S-SER BLD SML D
1D5F2     M S-SER BLD SML E
1D5F3     M S-SER BLD SML F
1D5F4     M S-SER BLD SML G
1D5F5     M S-SER BLD SML H
1D5F6     M S-SER BLD SML I
1D5F7     M S-SER BLD SML J
1D5F8     M S-SER BLD SML K
1D5F9     M S-SER BLD SML L
1D5FA     M S-SER BLD SML M
1D5FB     M S-SER BLD SML N
1D5FC     M S-SER BLD SML O
1D5FD     M S-SER BLD SML P
1D5FE     M S-SER BLD SML Q
1D5FF     M S-SER BLD SML R
1D600     M S-SER BLD SML S
1D601     M S-SER BLD SML T
1D602     M S-SER BLD SML U
1D603     M S-SER BLD SML V
1D604     M S-SER BLD SML W
1D605     M S-SER BLD SML X
1D606     M S-SER BLD SML Y
1D607     M S-SER BLD SML Z
1D608     M S-SER ITAL CAP A
1D609     M S-SER ITAL CAP B
1D60A     M S-SER ITAL CAP C
1D60B     M S-SER ITAL CAP D
1D60C     M S-SER ITAL CAP E
1D60D     M S-SER ITAL CAP F
1D60E     M S-SER ITAL CAP G
1D60F     M S-SER ITAL CAP H
1D610     M S-SER ITAL CAP I
1D611     M S-SER ITAL CAP J
1D612     M S-SER ITAL CAP K
1D613     M S-SER ITAL CAP L
1D614     M S-SER ITAL CAP M
1D615     M S-SER ITAL CAP N
1D616     M S-SER ITAL CAP O
1D617     M S-SER ITAL CAP P
1D618     M S-SER ITAL CAP Q
1D619     M S-SER ITAL CAP R
1D61A     M S-SER ITAL CAP S
1D61B     M S-SER ITAL CAP T
1D61C     M S-SER ITAL CAP U
1D61D     M S-SER ITAL CAP V
1D61E     M S-SER ITAL CAP W
1D61F     M S-SER ITAL CAP X
1D620     M S-SER ITAL CAP Y
1D621     M S-SER ITAL CAP Z
1D622     M S-SER ITAL SML A
1D623     M S-SER ITAL SML B
1D624     M S-SER ITAL SML C
1D625     M S-SER ITAL SML D
1D626     M S-SER ITAL SML E
1D627     M S-SER ITAL SML F
1D628     M S-SER ITAL SML G
1D629     M S-SER ITAL SML H
1D62A     M S-SER ITAL SML I
1D62B     M S-SER ITAL SML J
1D62C     M S-SER ITAL SML K
1D62D     M S-SER ITAL SML L
1D62E     M S-SER ITAL SML M
1D62F     M S-SER ITAL SML N
1D630     M S-SER ITAL SML O
1D631     M S-SER ITAL SML P
1D632     M S-SER ITAL SML Q
1D633     M S-SER ITAL SML R
1D634     M S-SER ITAL SML S
1D635     M S-SER ITAL SML T
1D636     M S-SER ITAL SML U
1D637     M S-SER ITAL SML V
1D638     M S-SER ITAL SML W
1D639     M S-SER ITAL SML X
1D63A     M S-SER ITAL SML Y
1D63B     M S-SER ITAL SML Z
1D63C     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP A
1D63D     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP B
1D63E     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP C
1D63F     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP D
1D640     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP E
1D641     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP F
1D642     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP G
1D643     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP H
1D644     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP I
1D645     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP J
1D646     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP K
1D647     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP L
1D648     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP M
1D649     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP N
1D64A     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP O
1D64B     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP P
1D64C     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP Q
1D64D     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP R
1D64E     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP S
1D64F     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP T
1D650     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP U
1D651     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP V
1D652     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP W
1D653     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP X
1D654     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP Y
1D655     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP Z
1D656     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML A
1D657     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML B
1D658     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML C
1D659     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML D
1D65A     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML E
1D65B     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML F
1D65C     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML G
1D65D     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML H
1D65E     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML I
1D65F     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML J
1D660     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML K
1D661     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML L
1D662     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML M
1D663     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML N
1D664     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML O
1D665     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML P
1D666     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML Q
1D667     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML R
1D668     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML S
1D669     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML T
1D66A     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML U
1D66B     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML V
1D66C     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML W
1D66D     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML X
1D66E     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML Y
1D66F     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML Z
1D670     M MNOSP CAP A
1D671     M MNOSP CAP B
1D672     M MNOSP CAP C
1D673     M MNOSP CAP D
1D674     M MNOSP CAP E
1D675     M MNOSP CAP F
1D676     M MNOSP CAP G
1D677     M MNOSP CAP H
1D678     M MNOSP CAP I
1D679     M MNOSP CAP J
1D67A     M MNOSP CAP K
1D67B     M MNOSP CAP L
1D67C     M MNOSP CAP M
1D67D     M MNOSP CAP N
1D67E     M MNOSP CAP O
1D67F     M MNOSP CAP P
1D680     M MNOSP CAP Q
1D681     M MNOSP CAP R
1D682     M MNOSP CAP S
1D683     M MNOSP CAP T
1D684     M MNOSP CAP U
1D685     M MNOSP CAP V
1D686     M MNOSP CAP W
1D687     M MNOSP CAP X
1D688     M MNOSP CAP Y
1D689     M MNOSP CAP Z
1D68A     M MNOSP SML A
1D68B     M MNOSP SML B
1D68C     M MNOSP SML C
1D68D     M MNOSP SML D
1D68E     M MNOSP SML E
1D68F     M MNOSP SML F
1D690     M MNOSP SML G
1D691     M MNOSP SML H
1D692     M MNOSP SML I
1D693     M MNOSP SML J
1D694     M MNOSP SML K
1D695     M MNOSP SML L
1D696     M MNOSP SML M
1D697     M MNOSP SML N
1D698     M MNOSP SML O
1D699     M MNOSP SML P
1D69A     M MNOSP SML Q
1D69B     M MNOSP SML R
1D69C     M MNOSP SML S
1D69D     M MNOSP SML T
1D69E     M MNOSP SML U
1D69F     M MNOSP SML V
1D6A0     M MNOSP SML W
1D6A1     M MNOSP SML X
1D6A2     M MNOSP SML Y
1D6A3     M MNOSP SML Z
1D6A4     M ITAL SML DOTLESS I
1D6A5     M ITAL SML DOTLESS J
1D6A6     <unassigned-1D6A6>
1D6A7     <unassigned-1D6A7>
1D6A8     M BLD CAP ALPHA
1D6A9     M BLD CAP BETA
1D6AA     M BLD CAP GAMA
1D6AB     M BLD CAP DELTA
1D6AC     M BLD CAP EPSILON
1D6AD     M BLD CAP ZETA
1D6AE     M BLD CAP ETA
1D6AF     M BLD CAP THETA
1D6B0     M BLD CAP IOTA
1D6B1     M BLD CAP KAPPA
1D6B2     M BLD CAP LAMA
1D6B3     M BLD CAP M
1D6B4     M BLD CAP NU
1D6B5     M BLD CAP XI
1D6B6     M BLD CAP OMCRON
1D6B7     M BLD CAP PI
1D6B8     M BLD CAP RHO
1D6B9     M BLD CAP THETA SYMOL
1D6BA     M BLD CAP SIGM
1D6BB     M BLD CAP TAU
1D6BC     M BLD CAP UPSILON
1D6BD     M BLD CAP PHI
1D6BE     M BLD CAP CHI
1D6BF     M BLD CAP PSI
1D6C0     M BLD CAP OMGA
1D6C1     M BLD NABLA
1D6C2     M BLD SML ALPHA
1D6C3     M BLD SML BETA
1D6C4     M BLD SML GAMA
1D6C5     M BLD SML DELTA
1D6C6     M BLD SML EPSILON
1D6C7     M BLD SML ZETA
1D6C8     M BLD SML ETA
1D6C9     M BLD SML THETA
1D6CA     M BLD SML IOTA
1D6CB     M BLD SML KAPPA
1D6CC     M BLD SML LAMA
1D6CD     M BLD SML M
1D6CE     M BLD SML NU
1D6CF     M BLD SML XI
1D6D0     M BLD SML OMCRON
1D6D1     M BLD SML PI
1D6D2     M BLD SML RHO
1D6D3     M BLD SML FINAL SIGM
1D6D4     M BLD SML SIGM
1D6D5     M BLD SML TAU
1D6D6     M BLD SML UPSILON
1D6D7     M BLD SML PHI
1D6D8     M BLD SML CHI
1D6D9     M BLD SML PSI
1D6DA     M BLD SML OMGA
1D6DB     M BLD PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
1D6DC     M BLD EPSILON SYMOL
1D6DD     M BLD THETA SYMOL
1D6DE     M BLD KAPPA SYMOL
1D6DF     M BLD PHI SYMOL
1D6E0     M BLD RHO SYMOL
1D6E1     M BLD PI SYMOL
1D6E2     M ITAL CAP ALPHA
1D6E3     M ITAL CAP BETA
1D6E4     M ITAL CAP GAMA
1D6E5     M ITAL CAP DELTA
1D6E6     M ITAL CAP EPSILON
1D6E7     M ITAL CAP ZETA
1D6E8     M ITAL CAP ETA
1D6E9     M ITAL CAP THETA
1D6EA     M ITAL CAP IOTA
1D6EB     M ITAL CAP KAPPA
1D6EC     M ITAL CAP LAMA
1D6ED     M ITAL CAP M
1D6EE     M ITAL CAP NU
1D6EF     M ITAL CAP XI
1D6F0     M ITAL CAP OMCRON
1D6F1     M ITAL CAP PI
1D6F2     M ITAL CAP RHO
1D6F3     M ITAL CAP THETA SYMOL
1D6F4     M ITAL CAP SIGM
1D6F5     M ITAL CAP TAU
1D6F6     M ITAL CAP UPSILON
1D6F7     M ITAL CAP PHI
1D6F8     M ITAL CAP CHI
1D6F9     M ITAL CAP PSI
1D6FA     M ITAL CAP OMGA
1D6FB     M ITAL NABLA
1D6FC     M ITAL SML ALPHA
1D6FD     M ITAL SML BETA
1D6FE     M ITAL SML GAMA
1D6FF     M ITAL SML DELTA
1D700     M ITAL SML EPSILON
1D701     M ITAL SML ZETA
1D702     M ITAL SML ETA
1D703     M ITAL SML THETA
1D704     M ITAL SML IOTA
1D705     M ITAL SML KAPPA
1D706     M ITAL SML LAMA
1D707     M ITAL SML M
1D708     M ITAL SML NU
1D709     M ITAL SML XI
1D70A     M ITAL SML OMCRON
1D70B     M ITAL SML PI
1D70C     M ITAL SML RHO
1D70D     M ITAL SML FINAL SIGM
1D70E     M ITAL SML SIGM
1D70F     M ITAL SML TAU
1D710     M ITAL SML UPSILON
1D711     M ITAL SML PHI
1D712     M ITAL SML CHI
1D713     M ITAL SML PSI
1D714     M ITAL SML OMGA
1D715     M ITAL PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
1D716     M ITAL EPSILON SYMOL
1D717     M ITAL THETA SYMOL
1D718     M ITAL KAPPA SYMOL
1D719     M ITAL PHI SYMOL
1D71A     M ITAL RHO SYMOL
1D71B     M ITAL PI SYMOL
1D71C     M BLD ITAL CAP ALPHA
1D71D     M BLD ITAL CAP BETA
1D71E     M BLD ITAL CAP GAMA
1D71F     M BLD ITAL CAP DELTA
1D720     M BLD ITAL CAP EPSILON
1D721     M BLD ITAL CAP ZETA
1D722     M BLD ITAL CAP ETA
1D723     M BLD ITAL CAP THETA
1D724     M BLD ITAL CAP IOTA
1D725     M BLD ITAL CAP KAPPA
1D726     M BLD ITAL CAP LAMA
1D727     M BLD ITAL CAP M
1D728     M BLD ITAL CAP NU
1D729     M BLD ITAL CAP XI
1D72A     M BLD ITAL CAP OMCRON
1D72B     M BLD ITAL CAP PI
1D72C     M BLD ITAL CAP RHO
1D72D     M BLD ITAL CAP THETA SYMOL
1D72E     M BLD ITAL CAP SIGM
1D72F     M BLD ITAL CAP TAU
1D730     M BLD ITAL CAP UPSILON
1D731     M BLD ITAL CAP PHI
1D732     M BLD ITAL CAP CHI
1D733     M BLD ITAL CAP PSI
1D734     M BLD ITAL CAP OMGA
1D735     M BLD ITAL NABLA
1D736     M BLD ITAL SML ALPHA
1D737     M BLD ITAL SML BETA
1D738     M BLD ITAL SML GAMA
1D739     M BLD ITAL SML DELTA
1D73A     M BLD ITAL SML EPSILON
1D73B     M BLD ITAL SML ZETA
1D73C     M BLD ITAL SML ETA
1D73D     M BLD ITAL SML THETA
1D73E     M BLD ITAL SML IOTA
1D73F     M BLD ITAL SML KAPPA
1D740     M BLD ITAL SML LAMA
1D741     M BLD ITAL SML M
1D742     M BLD ITAL SML NU
1D743     M BLD ITAL SML XI
1D744     M BLD ITAL SML OMCRON
1D745     M BLD ITAL SML PI
1D746     M BLD ITAL SML RHO
1D747     M BLD ITAL SML FINAL SIGM
1D748     M BLD ITAL SML SIGM
1D749     M BLD ITAL SML TAU
1D74A     M BLD ITAL SML UPSILON
1D74B     M BLD ITAL SML PHI
1D74C     M BLD ITAL SML CHI
1D74D     M BLD ITAL SML PSI
1D74E     M BLD ITAL SML OMGA
1D74F     M BLD ITAL PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
1D750     M BLD ITAL EPSILON SYMOL
1D751     M BLD ITAL THETA SYMOL
1D752     M BLD ITAL KAPPA SYMOL
1D753     M BLD ITAL PHI SYMOL
1D754     M BLD ITAL RHO SYMOL
1D755     M BLD ITAL PI SYMOL
1D756     M S-SER BLD CAP ALPHA
1D757     M S-SER BLD CAP BETA
1D758     M S-SER BLD CAP GAMA
1D759     M S-SER BLD CAP DELTA
1D75A     M S-SER BLD CAP EPSILON
1D75B     M S-SER BLD CAP ZETA
1D75C     M S-SER BLD CAP ETA
1D75D     M S-SER BLD CAP THETA
1D75E     M S-SER BLD CAP IOTA
1D75F     M S-SER BLD CAP KAPPA
1D760     M S-SER BLD CAP LAMA
1D761     M S-SER BLD CAP M
1D762     M S-SER BLD CAP NU
1D763     M S-SER BLD CAP XI
1D764     M S-SER BLD CAP OMCRON
1D765     M S-SER BLD CAP PI
1D766     M S-SER BLD CAP RHO
1D767     M S-SER BLD CAP THETA SYMOL
1D768     M S-SER BLD CAP SIGM
1D769     M S-SER BLD CAP TAU
1D76A     M S-SER BLD CAP UPSILON
1D76B     M S-SER BLD CAP PHI
1D76C     M S-SER BLD CAP CHI
1D76D     M S-SER BLD CAP PSI
1D76E     M S-SER BLD CAP OMGA
1D76F     M S-SER BLD NABLA
1D770     M S-SER BLD SML ALPHA
1D771     M S-SER BLD SML BETA
1D772     M S-SER BLD SML GAMA
1D773     M S-SER BLD SML DELTA
1D774     M S-SER BLD SML EPSILON
1D775     M S-SER BLD SML ZETA
1D776     M S-SER BLD SML ETA
1D777     M S-SER BLD SML THETA
1D778     M S-SER BLD SML IOTA
1D779     M S-SER BLD SML KAPPA
1D77A     M S-SER BLD SML LAMA
1D77B     M S-SER BLD SML M
1D77C     M S-SER BLD SML NU
1D77D     M S-SER BLD SML XI
1D77E     M S-SER BLD SML OMCRON
1D77F     M S-SER BLD SML PI
1D780     M S-SER BLD SML RHO
1D781     M S-SER BLD SML FINAL SIGM
1D782     M S-SER BLD SML SIGM
1D783     M S-SER BLD SML TAU
1D784     M S-SER BLD SML UPSILON
1D785     M S-SER BLD SML PHI
1D786     M S-SER BLD SML CHI
1D787     M S-SER BLD SML PSI
1D788     M S-SER BLD SML OMGA
1D789     M S-SER BLD PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
1D78A     M S-SER BLD EPSILON SYMOL
1D78B     M S-SER BLD THETA SYMOL
1D78C     M S-SER BLD KAPPA SYMOL
1D78D     M S-SER BLD PHI SYMOL
1D78E     M S-SER BLD RHO SYMOL
1D78F     M S-SER BLD PI SYMOL
1D790     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP ALPHA
1D791     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP BETA
1D792     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP GAMA
1D793     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP DELTA
1D794     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP EPSILON
1D795     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP ZETA
1D796     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP ETA
1D797     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP THETA
1D798     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP IOTA
1D799     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP KAPPA
1D79A     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP LAMA
1D79B     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP M
1D79C     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP NU
1D79D     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP XI
1D79E     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP OMCRON
1D79F     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP PI
1D7A0     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP RHO
1D7A1     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP THETA SYMOL
1D7A2     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP SIGM
1D7A3     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP TAU
1D7A4     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP UPSILON
1D7A5     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP PHI
1D7A6     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP CHI
1D7A7     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP PSI
1D7A8     M S-SER BLD ITAL CAP OMGA
1D7A9     M S-SER BLD ITAL NABLA
1D7AA     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML ALPHA
1D7AB     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML BETA
1D7AC     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML GAMA
1D7AD     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML DELTA
1D7AE     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML EPSILON
1D7AF     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML ZETA
1D7B0     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML ETA
1D7B1     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML THETA
1D7B2     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML IOTA
1D7B3     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML KAPPA
1D7B4     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML LAMA
1D7B5     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML M
1D7B6     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML NU
1D7B7     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML XI
1D7B8     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML OMCRON
1D7B9     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML PI
1D7BA     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML RHO
1D7BB     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML FINAL SIGM
1D7BC     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML SIGM
1D7BD     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML TAU
1D7BE     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML UPSILON
1D7BF     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML PHI
1D7C0     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML CHI
1D7C1     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML PSI
1D7C2     M S-SER BLD ITAL SML OMGA
1D7C3     M S-SER BLD ITAL PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
1D7C4     M S-SER BLD ITAL EPSILON SYMOL
1D7C5     M S-SER BLD ITAL THETA SYMOL
1D7C6     M S-SER BLD ITAL KAPPA SYMOL
1D7C7     M S-SER BLD ITAL PHI SYMOL
1D7C8     M S-SER BLD ITAL RHO SYMOL
1D7C9     M S-SER BLD ITAL PI SYMOL
1D7CA     M BLD CAP DIGAMA
1D7CB     M BLD SML DIGAMA
1D7CC     <unassigned-1D7CC>
1D7CD     <unassigned-1D7CD>
1D7CE     M BLD DIGIT ZERO
1D7CF     M BLD DIGIT ONE
1D7D0     M BLD DIGIT TWO
1D7D1     M BLD DIGIT THREE
1D7D2     M BLD DIGIT FOUR
1D7D3     M BLD DIGIT FIVE
1D7D4     M BLD DIGIT SIX
1D7D5     M BLD DIGIT SEVEN
1D7D6     M BLD DIGIT EIGHT
1D7D7     M BLD DIGIT NINE
1D7D8     M DBL-STR DIGIT ZERO
1D7D9     M DBL-STR DIGIT ONE
1D7DA     M DBL-STR DIGIT TWO
1D7DB     M DBL-STR DIGIT THREE
1D7DC     M DBL-STR DIGIT FOUR
1D7DD     M DBL-STR DIGIT FIVE
1D7DE     M DBL-STR DIGIT SIX
1D7DF     M DBL-STR DIGIT SEVEN
1D7E0     M DBL-STR DIGIT EIGHT
1D7E1     M DBL-STR DIGIT NINE
1D7E2     M S-SER DIGIT ZERO
1D7E3     M S-SER DIGIT ONE
1D7E4     M S-SER DIGIT TWO
1D7E5     M S-SER DIGIT THREE
1D7E6     M S-SER DIGIT FOUR
1D7E7     M S-SER DIGIT FIVE
1D7E8     M S-SER DIGIT SIX
1D7E9     M S-SER DIGIT SEVEN
1D7EA     M S-SER DIGIT EIGHT
1D7EB     M S-SER DIGIT NINE
1D7EC     M S-SER BLD DIGIT ZERO
1D7ED     M S-SER BLD DIGIT ONE
1D7EE     M S-SER BLD DIGIT TWO
1D7EF     M S-SER BLD DIGIT THREE
1D7F0     M S-SER BLD DIGIT FOUR
1D7F1     M S-SER BLD DIGIT FIVE
1D7F2     M S-SER BLD DIGIT SIX
1D7F3     M S-SER BLD DIGIT SEVEN
1D7F4     M S-SER BLD DIGIT EIGHT
1D7F5     M S-SER BLD DIGIT NINE
1D7F6     M MNOSP DIGIT ZERO
1D7F7     M MNOSP DIGIT ONE
1D7F8     M MNOSP DIGIT TWO
1D7F9     M MNOSP DIGIT THREE
1D7FA     M MNOSP DIGIT FOUR
1D7FB     M MNOSP DIGIT FIVE
1D7FC     M MNOSP DIGIT SIX
1D7FD     M MNOSP DIGIT SEVEN
1D7FE     M MNOSP DIGIT EIGHT
1D7FF     M MNOSP DIGIT NINE
```

Comment: this works like a charm removing this bold chars, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I thought this would be an uppercase/lowercase problem. You can likely follow the same with proper unicodes that you might want to find out.

> One problem with your expressions might be that `+` might be missing.

---

My guess is that maybe this expression might work:

```
([\x{0041}-\x{005A}]+)
```

*if everything might be uppercase*, or maybe some expressions similar to:

```
([\x{0041}-\x{005A}]{2,})
```

if we just want to replace `SONYA` and not `S O N Y A`.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPN8tu/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
$re = '/([\x{0041}-\x{005A}]+)/u';
$str = 'SONYA';
$subst = '\\L$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

#### Reference

[unicode of lower case and upper case letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495231/6553328)

Comment: This regex don't remove bold chars or replace, take in mind this: correct word is  (bolder) and not SONYA. I need remove it or replace for correct char without bold