# Regular expression to match unicode block, or index range

Tags: php, regex, unicode, pcre

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match any characters in a unicode block - specifically the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1D400) block.

The intention here is to identify the use of content using Unicode characters to get different formatting on their text, like bold or italic text when it's not supported generally. There are plenty of websites, [like this one](https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=noreply%40example.com) that help users convert text.

I've tried using the shorthand property code, but it doesn't seem to match all characters I'd expect from the block.

```php
preg_match('/\p{Sm}/i', '') === 1; // false
```

It doesn't appear as though PHP supports the named variants either, so I can't do something like `\p{Math}`.

I believe I need to target the block range - which is from U+1D400 - U+1D7FF, but I cannot work out how to correctly build this regex. This is how I thought I would have it work, but it doesn't appear to work.

```php
preg_match('/\x{1D400}-\x{1D7FF}/i', '') === 1; // false
```

---

I would expect none of these characters to match (typed straight on my keyboard):

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

I would expect every single one of these characters to match (same as above, converted to Math bold using the link above):

Comment: You assumed the wrong property. `` is `Nd`, not `Sm`:  `› uniprops ␤U+1D7EE ‹› \N{MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD DIGIT TWO}␤\w \d \pN \p{Nd}␤All Alnum X_POSIX_Alnum Any Assigned ID_Continue Is_IDC Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded CWKCF Common Zyyy Decimal_Number X_POSIX_Digit Digit Nd N Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase IDC Math Math_Alphanum Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols InMathAlphanum Number Print X_POSIX_Print Unicode Word X_POSIX_Word XID_Continue XIDC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this expression might work, not sure though:

```
$re = '/[\x{1D400}-\x{1D7FF}]+/su';
$str = '';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

---

```
\p{S} or \p{Symbol}: math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.
\p{Sm} or \p{Math_Symbol}: any mathematical symbol.
\p{Sc} or \p{Currency_Symbol}: any currency sign.
\p{Sk} or \p{Modifier_Symbol}: a combining character (mark) as a full character on its own.
\p{So} or \p{Other_Symbol}: various symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs, or combining characters.
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mAvbEt/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mAvbEt/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### Reference

[RegEx for Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839601/remove-bold-characters-from-string-no-have-b-tag/56839951#56839951)

[Unicode Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: This works great - thanks for the additional links too, it'll be easier to have a play now that I've got a working base to start from.